# English Sentence to Camel-cased method name

Tags: ruby, string, camelcasing

I had to convert a series of sentences into camel-cased method names. I ended writing something for it. I am still curious if there's something simpler for it.

Given the string `a = "This is a test."` output `thisIsATest`

I used for following:

```
a.downcase.gsub(/\s\w/){|b| b[-1,1].upcase }
```

Comment: Are you using Rails, or just Plain Old Ruby Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's better as your solution but it should do the trick:

```
>> "This is a test.".titleize.split(" ").join.camelize(:lower)
=> "thisIsATest."
```

- titleize: uppercase every first letter of each word
- split(" ").join: create an array with each word and join to squeeze the spaces out
- camelize(:lower): make the first letter lowercase

You can find some more fun functions in the Rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html

Comment: Will only work in Rails, but its good to have a list of those methods!

Answer (score 2):

```
"active_record".camelize(:lower)
```

output : "activeRecord"

use these

Answer (score 1):

```
"Some string for you".gsub(/\s+/,'_').camelize(:lower) #=> "someStringForYou"
```

1. gsub: Replace spaces by underscores
2. camelize: java-like method camelcase

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the 'English' gem, available at http://english.rubyforge.org/

```
require 'english/case'

a = "This is a test."

a.camelcase().uncapitalize() # => 'thisIsATest
```